# Insert large list of fields and values into feature class

Tags: arcpy, cursor, feature-class

I want to create a toolbox
I have a list of point coordinates, that define a polygon and a list of attributes, that each polygon has.
`points_list = [(323917.71, 479699.45), (323923.36, 479699.74), (323923.89, 479709.52), (323918.24, 479709.23)],
attributes = [('ADDRESSID', '5'), ('BUILDINGID', '4'), ('LANDID', '35'), ... ]`

I want to insert the information into a feature class. I also want to define the projection, that would be selected by the user, inside the Toolbox.

I have tried:

```
list_of_fields = [key_value[0] for key_value in attributes ]
insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,
                                     ['SHAPE@', list_of_fields], spatial_ref)
polyArray = arcpy.Array()
for pointsPair in points_list:
    newPoint = arcpy.Point(*pointsPair)
    polyArray.add(newPoint)
newPoly = arcpy.Polygon(polyArray)
list_of_values = [key_value[1] for key_value in attributes ]
insertData = newPoly, object_id
insertCursor.insertRow(insertData)
```

Nothing is recorded in the feature class.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with this line:

```
insertData = newPoly, object_id
```

First of all what is object_id? Seems like a completely unrelated object, you want to insert a row that is your polygon and in your example 3 values.

You want to be constructing a tuple like this:

```
insertData = (newPoly,5,4,35)
```

Then insert it with:

```
insertCursor.insertRow(insertData)
```

Also and I appreciate this is a code "snippet" but there is no loop, it's a one time read your your lists `attributes` and `points_list`.

Comment: From the cursor assignment, I think OP was trying to do `insertData = [newPoly] + list_of_values`, and AFAIK, the list should be fine with InsertCursor.